# Transitive Dependencies

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

If I have the following relation:

Staff(staffNo(PK), sName, position, salary, branchNo, branchAddress)

Is it fair to say that staffNo -> branchAddress is a transitive dependency as staffNo -> branchNo and branchNo -> branchAddress

Sorry, I'm revising for an exam and transitive dependencies are throwing me a little...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

[Axiom of transitivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms#Axiom_of_transitivity)

I had the pleasure of having Bill Armstrong as my prof for my database course.